# Can't connect to Postgres database using PHP PDO and Docker

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, pdo

I am running a Docker app that is built on three images: `php:7.4-fpm`, `nginx:stable-alpine` and `postgres:alpine`.

I was previously attempting to use the image `php:7.4-fpm-alpine`, but apparently it does not come with the Postgres PDO driver, which was causing a `could not find driver` error. [This post](https://benpetering.com/posts/2020/10/25/php-and-postgres-with-docker.html) explains more about that, and how to fix it. I followed the steps in that post, including creating a `Dockerfile` for my PHP FPM service (though I did not create a PHP CLI service), and that remedied my driver issues. However, I am now getting the following error when I try to connect to my PSQL database using PDO:

`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 6432?`

I know my database is running (on port 6432) because I can access it from my terminal and from Positco, and have created tables after my Docker app was created. I also tried to connect to a database on port 5432 (through which my Postgres desktop app is running), but that did not work either. I also tried to restart my Postgres container, but that did not help.

Here is my PHP:

```
class Database {

    private $connection;

    private static $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $dsn = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=6432;dbname=db_my_test_app';
            $username = 'root';
            $password = 'secret';
            $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, self::$options);
            $this->connection = $connection;
            return $connection;      
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

$database = new Database();
```

...and my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

networks: 
    my_test_app:

services: 

    # nginx
    nginx-service:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx-container
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        volumes: 
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on: 
            - php-fpm-service
            - postgres-service
        networks: 
            - my_test_app  
  
    # php
    php-fpm-service:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
        container_name: php-fpm-container
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        working_dir: /var/www/project
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
        networks: 
            - my_test_app  

    # postgres
    postgres-service:
        image: postgres:alpine
        container_name: postgres-container
        ports: 
            - "6432:5432"
        volumes: 
            - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: root
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
            POSTGRES_DB: db_my_test_app
        networks: 
            - my_test_app
```

...and the PHP service `Dockerfile` (from the aforementioned site):

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
RUN ln -s /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i -e 's/;extension=pgsql/extension=pgsql/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i -e 's/;extension=pdo_pgsql/extension=pdo_pgsql/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Comment: Just a side note: you can install PHP extension in a much easier way by using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring docker under the default network mode: `bridge`. In order for the `php-fpm-service` to be able to access the `postgres-service` you need to make the following modifications:

In the `docker-compose.yml` file you'll need to add `depends_on` to `php-fpm-service`

```
# php
php-fpm-service:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
    container_name: php-fpm-container
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    working_dir: /var/www/project
    volumes:
        - ./app:/var/www/project
    networks: 
        - my_test_app  
    depends_on:
        - postgres-service
```

In your PHP config, you need modify `localhost` to `postgres-service` and using port 5432:

```
$dsn = 'pgsql:host=postgres-service;port=5432;dbname=db_my_test_app';
```

Comment: Thank you; this worked. Can you please explain why I must use port 5432 in the `$dsn` instead of 6432? Also, is there a place where I can learn more about Docker's network modes? I read and watched many tutorials about linking a database to PHP and nginx, and nothing about that was ever discussed.

Comment: @GingerandLavender If you use the default network mode, docker will isolate your containers on a private network, port 6432 is the port you specify so that components outside the docker can access the containers and inside the docker network, the containers still use port 5432 to access your postgres-service.You can read more about the docker network here: https://docs.docker.com/network/.